# Delete row within sortable: true in Grid with Local Data

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.1

I try to make a gridpanel with local data **http://jsfiddle.net/8um4T/**

This grid has **add and delete within** `sortable: true` in column, I will delete record by id (but my way fail with large data)

Here is my data

```
var simpleData = [];
var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: ['id', 'name',],
    data: simpleData
});
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    simpleData.push({id:''+i+'', name: 'name'+i});    
}
store.loadData(simpleData);
```

My tbar with a add button

```
tbar:[
    {    
        text:'Add',
        handler:function(){
            simpleData.push({id:'x', name: 'name'});
            store.loadData(simpleData);
        }
    }
]
```

My action column

```
{
    header: '',
    xtype: 'actioncolumn'
    , width: 50
    , items: [{ // Delete button
        icon: 'http://whatisextjs.com/BAHO/icons/cancel.png',
        tooltip: 'Delete'
        , handler: function(grids, rowIndex, colindex) {
            var record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);

            //Delete item in array
            // if data is large will don't working
            Ext.each(simpleData, function (items, idx) {            
                if (items.id == record.data.id) {
                    simpleData.splice(idx, 1);
                }
            });     

            //Delete record in store
            grid.store.removeAt(rowIndex); 
        }
    }]
}
```

if mydata is small then delete button will working. My data in my example is 20 record and that don't work

my idea is remove record from `store` after assign for `simpleData`. But how to do that or has another anyway to fix my problem thanks

```
                    //grid.store.removeAt(rowIndex); 
                    // simpleData = grid.store.data; // my idea is (but how)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break the loop after splicing the array by returning false. You are taking away one of the elements but the loop is not aware of it. So the last element will be undefined.

The loop will fail because the last 'items' parameter is not an object. So "items" is not an object and does not have an id.

The result is that you are removing that object from the array but you never get to the grid.store.removeAt(rowIndex); sentence. I would do:

```
Ext.each(simpleData, function (items, idx) {            
  if (items.id == record.data.id) {
    simpleData.splice(idx, 1);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: thank u, but if i want delete multi row by this way, I can't using return because it only delete one record in simpleData?

Comment: and What about my idea? Is that posible :)

Comment: Your right I would in that case ask if the items parameter exist before trying to get the 'id' property. Somethin like if(items && items.id === record.data.id)...

Comment: About your other idea, the problem is that grid.store.data is an object, not an array as you would need for 'simpleData'.